# When forking, is the 'else' block necessary?

Tags: c, linux, fork, ipc

```
   if (pid==0)
   {
     //child
   }
   else
   {
    //parent
     ...
   }
```

Why is the 'else' part necessary? isn't it implied that we are in the parent ?

Comment: Remember `fork()` can fail. If you don't test for failure you will run the parent code alone. `if (pid == -1) { perror("fork"); } else { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Personally, I use a switch statement with the 3 options: *-1* means failure; *0* means we are in the child; *default* means we are in the parent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> isn't it implied that we are in the parent ?

**No.** After a `fork()` call, there are *two* processes that run from exactly that same point in the code. Only one is the parent. The code you put in the `else` block is run *only* by the parent, just as the code inside the `if` block is run *only* by the child. Code that comes after the entire `if`/`else` statement is executed by both the child and the parent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary unless you want to do something with both the original(parent) and the new(child) processes.

```
if((pid = fork()) == 0){
    //child
}else{
    //parent
}
```